# scroll down only work one time in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the `javascript` code for scrolling down the page :

```
function down() { 
  var scrolled=0;
  scrolled=scrolled+1000;
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:  scrolled  },2500);
}
```

It works fine but it only works one time. If I click again it won't work. How can I find the way so this work as long as I click?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a constant (1000) for where to scroll to the page. Once you hit 1000 pixels from the top, telling it to scroll there again will do nothing.

Are you trying to scroll 1000 px from wherever you're at? To do that, you need to use the scroll distance:

```
var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
```

since you're using jQuery you can also use

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: Please note that the `pageYOffset` property doesn’t exist in IE < 9. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY for details.

Comment: Added jQuery property

Answer (score 1):

If you wаnt scroll +1000px whenever you call `down`, try this:

```
var down = (function() { 
  var scrolled=0;

  return function() {
    scrolled += 1000;
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:  scrolled  },2500);
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re always scrolling to the same position (1000). Whenever you call `down()`, you set `scrolled` to `0`.

You’ll need to define the `scrolled` variable outside the function scope.

**Example:**

```js
(function () {

    var scrolled = 0;

    function down() {
        scrolled=scrolled+1000;
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:  scrolled  },2500);
    }

    $('#scroll').click(down);

}());
```

(Assuming your button or link element that should trigger the scroll has the ID `scroll`)